# Update comment in Oracle SQL

Tags: oracle

I need to change(modify) comments in the table columns and comment to the table itself.
How can I do it?

Is there something like alter table command, that can do it?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/COMMENT.html#GUID-65F447C4-6914-4823-9691-F15D52DB74D7

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Simply run another comment command, e.g.

```
comment on table emp is 'List ofmployees';
comment on column emp.ename is 'Employee''s name';
```

as they will "overwrite" old comments.